# How does the paying option work in Candy Crush iOS?

Tags: ios, candy-crush-saga

When one runs out of moves in Candy Crush for iOS, what is the paying option for?

It shows a +5 number and a lollipop saying that I only need 1 more jellys and the price of $0.99

[image]

I'm surprised that they don't put more information about what it's being offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pay the $0.99, you will get:

- 5 more moves
- 3 Lollipop boosts

You can still lose, even with 5 more moves.  If you do, you'll be back on this screen again.  Thus, if you don't think you can win with just 5 moves, this is probably a terrible deal.  (Although I think it is a terrible deal all the time, but that's me)

The lollipop boosts can be used anytime, and they will break a candy in a single square, with all the effects that entails - so they will clear jelly underneath the candy, for instance.

Paying for this has no effect on your lives - paying for extra lives is a different thing altogether.

Comment: You forgot to mention that most people who buy things like this quickly become addicted and end up spending way too much money on them ;)

Comment: @Mkalafut The addiction or compulsion to games may be due to game designers designing the game as a virtual [Skinner Box](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWtvrPTbQ_c)